# Default ON DELETE on a database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How know the default behaviour configured of ON DELETE on a concrete database?

```
ON DELETE { NO ACTION | CASCADE | SET NULL | SET DEFAULT }
```

Comment: `SELECT delete_referential_action, * FROM sys.foreign_keys`. Garnish with joins on other system tables and/or `OBJECT_NAME`/`COL_NAME` to taste. The default if nothing is specified is always `NO ACTION`, with no way to change that across databases, so don't worry about that.

Comment: @JeroenMoster It says "0 rows affected". I only have in System Tables the tables sys.trace_xe_action_map and sys.trace_xe_event_map

Comment: My query retrieves what's configured for existing foreign keys. If you have no foreign keys, then it returns nothing. We *are* talking about foreign keys, right? :-P

Comment: You should also check by executing `sp_help [object_
name] `

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query to know more on cascade actions

```
select delete_referential_action_desc,
OBJECT_NAME(f.referenced_object_id) as pktblname,
OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) as fktblname,OBJECT_NAME(o.object_id) as fkname
 from sys.foreign_keys f
join
sys.objects o
on o.object_id=f.object_id
```